# New calculated table in DAX order by the count

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot, ssas-tabular

I am using SSAS Tabluar models and I am trying to create a calculated table based on the count of each subcategory.

```
ColumnA     ColumnB
SPN100      new
SPN100      old
SPN100      new
SPN200      new
SPN200      old
```

and I am trying to create a new table based on counts of `ColumnB`

```
Column A    Counts 
SPN100       3
SPN200       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMMARIZE` or `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`.

```
Summary = SUMMARIZE(Table, Table1[ColumnA], "Counts", COUNT(Table1[ColumnB]))

Summary = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table1[ColumnA], "Counts", COUNT(Table1[ColumnB]))
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis,I tried this in my new calculated table1 and it gives no results and no error also.

Comment: 1. Go to the Table on top and created new calculated table and entered this DAX expression =SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( Query[spn], "Counts", COUNT(Query[vin]))

Comment: Query is my table name where i have spn and vin attributes

Comment: Actually it s working when i changed the expression to COUNTA ,Thanks alot